# Using a Bearer token in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, webapi, bearer-token

I am using Power BI to call a bearer token. I have the bearer token and am able to call it into Postman pretty easily.

I have tried doing a blank query in Power M:

```
let
    apiUrl = "my_api_url",
    token="my_api_key",
    options = [Headers=[#"Authorization"="Bearer " & token ]],
    result = Json.Document(Web.Contents(apiUrl , options))
in
    #"result"
```

This didn't work.

Or putting the bearer token here:

[image: Access Web from Get data]

Or just adding the API token to the end of the website. https://myurl.com/API=444554

Answer (score 2):

If you receive a message asking you to edit the credentials, it could be due to various factors. Sometimes, Power BI might require you to specify authentication credentials at the data source level.

To resolve this, follow these steps:

Edit Credentials in the Query Editor:

a. Within the Query Editor, on the right panel, you should see a section indicating the data sources and whether credentials are required.

b. Click on the "Credentials required" or "Edit credentials" link.

c. Choose "Anonymous" if you are only using a Bearer token for authentication. In theory, if you're using a token, you shouldn't need to provide additional authentication.

d. Click "Connect" or "OK".